# css colors are different

Tags: css, colors, screen, color-scheme

I have noticed, that on different computers same css colors looks different, because on the monitor, or because of the color depth or because of the graphic card.

**For example**: the color `#f5f5f5` on some computers looks like `#ffffff`, or it became another color.

Is it possible to fix that?

Comment: Assuming you can calibrate the monitors you're talking about, this might help: http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: You can't. Every different browser on every different screen on every OS has a slightly different color balance and you just have to live with it.

If you are trying to make colors match up with images, I suggest using gif for your images however, as PNG or JPEG both contain color management tables that try to compensate for the screen, and end up rendering colors differently from CSS.

Ironically, because GIF is too dumb to know about color balancing, it's much easier to match GIF colors up with hex colors specified in the CSS.

Answer (score 4):

Actually you can't.

It fully depends on the monitor and the graphics card and the monitor's settings etc.

If you have a monitor at home, which is calibrated and do not want to add background colors by number but by image, you may have an improvement, but no guarantee for that

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, you can't.

The monitor will display the colours in the way that it chooses (the way the screen works and the colour profiles in use etc).

Different devices and different screens will display things slightly different. It's one of the joys of the industry!

Answer (score 1):

It is based on the calibration of your monitor and to my knowledge there is no way to compensate for it in CSS.

To figure out how to calibrate your monitor so that at least you can see what is really happening with your color schemes visit a site like this one:

[Calibrate Your Monitor](http://www.wikihow.com/Calibrate-Your-Monitor)