# CSS blending mode to replicate additive blending

Tags: css, colors

I'm trying to create an [RGB additive color model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) on my website.

I'm using the following code:

```css
#colorBox1 {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

#colorBox2 {
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

#colorBox3 {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

#colorBox4 {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="color">
  <div id="colorBox1" class="colorBox"></div>
  <div id="colorBox2" class="colorBox"></div>
  <div id="colorBox3" class="colorBox"></div>
  <div id="colorBox4" class="colorBox"></div>
</div>
```

** I've skipped some of the positioning rules to make the code as clear as possible*

So I was expecting the 3 colors to blend into white color of rgb(255, 255, 255). But when I preview the page the color is a little bit off-white. It is actually rgb(248, 255, 253). Although rgb(255, 255, 255) (colorBox4) does display as pure white of (255, 255, 255) - all via a color picker.

[image: color modes]

Is this it - [css colors are different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988092/css-colors-are-different)? 
Is it just the monitor?
Or is there a CSS blending method or a chain of CSS blending methods  where I can achieve "true" color additive mode?

Comment: How are you determining the color of the center section? When I run your test and use the color picker addon, I am seeing 255,255,255 in the center as expected

Comment: i guess using different browser might give you different results ... but for me , chrome or Firefox show me #fff ... Opera ? its really not what you would expect

Answer (score 1):

I am not seeing the results you are.  In this test the colors are correctly blended.  How are you determining the color of the blended region?

[image]

```css
.colorBox{
  position:absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
#colorBox1 {
    background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
    
}

#colorBox2 {
    background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
    mix-blend-mode: screen;
    left: 70px;
}

#colorBox3 {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    mix-blend-mode: screen;
    top: 70px;
    left:40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="color">
        <div id = "colorBox1" class="colorBox"></div>
        <div id = "colorBox2" class="colorBox"></div>
        <div id = "colorBox3" class="colorBox"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Just tried it on two monitors again (external BenQ, showing the above readings) and buitlin MacBook Retina display (shows 252, 253, 252). I used both builtin OSX color picker and a third party color picker tool. So, could it be that OSX color profiles are off?

Comment: I was using the chrome color picker addon.  IT shows all colors correctly.  I am on windows so don't have a lot of insight into the built in osx color picker.